# How to pass data properly when two VC is on same screen

Tags: swift, dependency-injection, uiviewcontroller

In my app, it has two ViewControllers on below same screen.

- `ViewControllerA` is an UIViewController, which includes a tableView.
- `ViewControllerB` is a containerView, which is on top of UITabBarController(root VC) as a child.

[image]

For now, I load data(songs array, index, etc.) in `viewWillAppear` of `ViewControllerA`, that would be in background queue. Meanwhile, `ViewControllerB` requires the same data when `ViewControllerA`'s data loading is complete.

Currently, I'm using Dependency Injection to keep a unique data source. Declare modelController reference in ViewController A and B, and use getter and setter to binding the data changes.

The problem is the songs array fetched from modelController in `ViewControllerB` is nil. Because `ViewControllerA` will set data on modelController when loading is completed. And `ViewControllerB` will use it from modelController in its `viewWillAppear`. But these two VC are on the same screen, how could I guaranty which one will go first? Also data loading is in background queue, so it is suppose to be delayed. Then if `ViewControllerB` needs that data in first place, it can't be.

My current thought is to load data on `ViewControllerB` too, so it will not rely on `ViewControllerA`'s result. Or add some observer/listener to message `ViewControllerB` when data is ready. I think it is kind of architecture stuff, I need advices from experienced guys, any hints are appreciated!

**Create and inject the ModelController**

```
func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {
    guard let _ = (scene as? UIWindowScene) else { return }
    
    guard let rootViewController = window?.rootViewController as? TabBarController else {
        fatalError("Unexpected Root View Controller")
    }
    
    // create dependency injection here
    rootViewController.modelController = ModelController()
    AudioManager.shared.modelController = rootViewController.modelController
}
```

**ModelController**

```
enum PlayMode: String {
    case cycle = "repeat"
    case cycleOne = "repeat.1"
    case shuffle = "shuffle"
}

class ModelController {
    var songs: [Song]? = nil
    var position: Int = 0
    var playMode = PlayMode.cycle
}
```

**Getter and Setter**

```
var modelController: ModelController!

var songs: [Song]?
{
    get { modelController.songs }
    set { modelController.songs = newValue }
}

var position: Int
{
    get { modelController.position }
    set { modelController.position = newValue }
}
```

**Load data in `ViewControllerA`.**

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(true)
        
    loadData()
}

func loadData() {
    self.showSpinner()
    songs?.removeAll()
    DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async { [weak self] in
        self?.songs = DataFetcher.shared.fetchMetaData().0
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            print("data load complete")
            self?.table.reloadData()
            self?.removeSpinner()
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

so what you said is also possible

> observer/listener to message ViewControllerB when data is ready

You can have a **shared data class** which both the `vcA` and `vcB` use. For example

```
class SharedData {

    static let shared = SharedData()

    // Use didLoad as a flag for both ViewControllers
    var didLoad: Bool {
       return self.data != nil
    }

    var data: SomeData!

    private init() {
      fetchData()
    }
}
```

In this answer there is a function called `fetchData` which is in the same class. You can invoke the `fetchData` function in the background, and use the `didLoad` or `data` as flags for displaying/calling any other function you require. This class is also a `singleton` meaning there will be one instance of this class throughout your applications - So you can use this anywhere in your application.

This is merely an example. You can extend this to your needs such as adding a delegate to listen for callbacks when data is loaded so you can do something in both VCs.

Or you can simply use a `protocol` from `vcA` (assuming `vcA` triggers the network call) and once the data is loaded you can pass it to `vcB`

Comment: Thanks, I create a DataListener protocol to broadcast message to that ViewControllerB when data loading complete. Although I use denpendency injection instead of Singleton. Well, I would refactor my project then to see if this approach works fine.